# Adding events sent in method xml documentation

Tags: c#

Is it possible to specify which events are sent by a method in the method xml doc ?
For exception, there is the exception tag, but I didn't find anything for events.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a specific tag for it, no.
You could use [typeparam](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags?redirectedfrom=MSDN#typeparam) as an alternative.

Take a look at the paragraph [User-defined tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags?redirectedfrom=MSDN#user-defined-tags). There is a mention of the Sandcastle XML comments project which has an [event](https://ewsoftware.github.io/XMLCommentsGuide/html/81bf7ad3-45dc-452f-90d5-87ce2494a182.htm) tag